# What is state transition probability in an MDP? A matrix or a 3-D tensor?

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I find the following written in places:

$P$ is a state transition probability matrix,

$P_{ss'}^{a} = P[S_{t+1} = s' | S_t = s, A_t = a]$ ([notes by david silver](https://www.davidsilver.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/MDP.pdf) - slide 24 and, sutton and barto)

How is it that that is a matrix? Is not that a 3-D tensor? I think we would have a state transition matrix for every action and on the whole, it would be a 3-d tensor.